# Unmarshal XML with variable child types

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<smses count="500">
  <sms id="1" text="hi" sms_specific_field="blah" />
  <sms id="2" text="what's up?" sms_specific_field="blah" />
  <mms id="3" text="null" text_only="0">
    <parts>
      <part seq="-1" content="image/jpeg" text="null" data="base64_data_here==" />
      <part seq="0" content="text/plain" text="Check it out!" />
    </parts>
  </mms>
  <sms id="4" text="what's up?" sms_specific_field="blah" />
</smses>
```

The `sms` and `mms` children of `smses` can occur in any order. I'd like to unmarshal this data into native Go structs. I thought I could use a slice of interfaces for those like:

```
Messages []interface{} `xml:",any"`  // not sure if this is correct
```

But then how do I get that into marshaled structs for each type?

I was thinking of approaching it like so but not sure if this works to cover both and don't want to spend all the time writing this for structs that will have a ton more attributes if this whole approach won't work anyways:

```
type Messages struct {
    XMLName       xml.Name   `xml:"smses"`
    Count         string     `xml:"count,attr"`
    MessageList   []Message  `xml:",any"` // <-- will this work?
}

type Message struct {
    SMS           SMS        `xml:"sms"`
    MMS           MMS        `xml:"mms"`
    ID            string     `xml"id,attr"`
    Text          string     `xml:"text,attr"`
}

type SMS struct {
    XMLName       xml.Name   `xml:"sms"`
    SMSSpecField  string     `xml:"sms_specific_field,attr"`
}

type MMS struct {
    XMLName       xml.Name   `xml:"mms"`
    TextOnly      string     `xml:"text_only,attr"`
    Parts         []Part     `xml:"parts"`
}

... And so on - but I don't know if this approach works / makes sense
```

How do I design my structs in order to unmarshal this XML including attributes and child items?

Comment: Turning structs into XML is marshalling. Turning XML into structs is unmarshalling.

Comment: You note that you don't know if the given approach works - have you tried it? If so, what issues did you have with it?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/SlAtGDTXnU4 I fail to see how trying it out from the small sample you provided takes more time than writing up a question on SO.

Comment: @Adrian I actually have a ton of attributes in each struct and if this method won't work I don't want to take the time to write them all. So I am trying to understand the correct approach to this before wasting time going down a path that is a dead end. If I can unmarshal them and ignore fields (by not including them, not by using `xml:"-"` tag), then I can definitely test but I don't know if that works or not. Can't find good reference explaining xml in one place including tags, these type of relationships, etc. --> everything I find covers json more thoroughly.

Comment: They work very similarly. If you unmarshal XML into a struct, and the XML has elements/attributes that aren't found in the struct, they're ignored.

Comment: @Adrian well that makes life much easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach would be something like this:

```
type Messages struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"smses"`
    Count   string   `xml:"count,attr"`
    MMS     []MMS    `xml:"mms"`
    SMS     []SMS    `xml:"sms"`
}
```

This will unmarshal all child `mms` elements into `MMS` and all child `sms` elements into `SMS`. You can then iterate these for further processing as necessary, e.g. embedding them into `Message` objects and putting those into a combined slice. This will lose the original XML source order, however.

Comment: Where I'm still lost is the shared fields like ID and Text (there are actually a lot of shared fields in my real data set). This approach means I just duplicate them under each struct. Is that the best way?

Comment: You can duplicate them, or you can put the shared fields into their own struct and embed it in each of the other structs.

Comment: If I ignore attributes, will it still unmarshal ok? In other words, I will have all the fields but skip some attributes.

Comment: Ignore them how?

Comment: Not add them to my struct

Comment: Yes. If the XML has elements/attributes not found in the struct, they just won't be unmarshalled.