# Unmarshal XML with variable child types while preserving order of children

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I have an XML structure with a variable set of child elements. I want to unmarshal these child objects into a structure while preserving their order. I am currently using `encoding/xml` to unmarshal the xml, but this is not a strict requirement.

Sample XML structure:

```xml
<protocol>
    // ... more packet elements
    <packet family="Npc" action="Player">
        <comment>Main NPC update message</comment>
        <array name="positions" type="NpcUpdatePosition"/>
        <break/>
        <array name="attacks" type="NpcUpdateAttack"/>
        <break/>
        <array name="chats" type="NpcUpdateChat"/>
        <break/>
        <field name="hp" type="short" optional="true"/>
        <field name="tp" type="short" optional="true"/>
    </packet>
    // ... more packet elements
</protocol>
```

The variable elements to which I'm referring are child elements of the `packet` elements.

My models look like this:

```golang
type Protocol struct {
    Packets []ProtocolPacket `xml:"packet"`
}

type ProtocolPacket struct {
    Family       string                `xml:"family,attr"`
    Action       string                `xml:"action,attr"`
    Instructions /* ??? */             `xml:",any"`
    Comment      string                `xml:"comment"`
}
```

In this XML spec, there are a number of different elements such as `array`, `break`, and `field`, shown in the above sample, that need to be coalesced into a single slice while maintaining their order. These are referred to generally as "instructions". (`comment` in the example is a special case that should only ever be seen once).

I'm completely stumped on how to model the list of "instructions". One idea I had was to create an interface `ProtocolInstruction` with a custom unmarshaller that assigned an implementation depending on the element type, but I don't think this pattern would work, as you need to know the receiver type ahead of time for the unmarshal function to satisfy the appropriate interface.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795458/unmarshal-xml-with-variable-child-types), but the suggested answer does not preserve the order of elements between different element names. Another idea I had was to use this method but write custom unmarshallers for each type that increment a counter and store the element index - that way even if order isn't preserved, it can at least be retrieved. However, this seems like a lot of work and a messy implementation, so I'm searching for alternatives.

**Is there any way to unmarshal variable child XML elements while preserving their order in go?**

Comment: I'm a little unclear about the structure of your data. Your example XML contains `array` elements which aren't represented in your `ProtocolPacket` struct. Your struct has an `Instructions` member and I'm not sure how that relates to your data. I'm also unclear what the `<break>` elements are and how they should be handled.

Comment: Along with @larsks comment about being unclear, please edit your question to include the sample struct the XML you shared should unmarshal to (regardless of how); show us what you expect.

Comment: @larsks sorry for being unclear, I've edited my question, hopefully it makes more sense. The question isn't about how to specifically model each individual element, rather how to  take a set of disparate elements and represent them in a single collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

Drawing on the highest-rated answer (so far) to [unmarshal extra attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49950640/246801), you could create the simple structs:

```golang
type Protocol struct {
    Packets []Packet `xml:"packet"`
}

type Packet struct {
    Family  string `xml:"family,attr"`
    Action  string `xml:"action,attr"`
    Comment string `xml:"comment"`

    Instructions []Instruction `xml:",any"`
}

type Instruction struct {
    Name  xml.Name
    Attrs []xml.Attr `xml:",any,attr"`
}
```

Any elements in a packet not handled by the more precise rules at the top of the Packet struct will be passed to Instruction which will decode the element into its name and a slice of its attributes.

Unmarshalling your sample XML will produce a var protocol with Packets.Instructions that contain rather raw XML values (which you can see me handling in the String method, later):

```golang
var protocol Protocol
xml.Unmarshal([]byte(opXML), &protocol)

for _, it := range protocol.Packets[0].Instructions {
    fmt.Println(it)
}
```

```
{name:array attrs:{name:positions type:NpcUpdatePosition}}
{name:break attrs:{}}
{name:array attrs:{name:attacks type:NpcUpdateAttack}}
{name:break attrs:{}}
{name:array attrs:{name:chats type:NpcUpdateChat}}
{name:break attrs:{}}
{name:field attrs:{name:hp type:short optional:true}}
{name:field attrs:{name:tp type:short optional:true}}
```

The String method for Instruction:

```golang
func (it Instruction) String() (s string) {
    s += fmt.Sprintf("{name:%s", it.Name.Local)
    s += " attrs:{"
    sep := ""
    for _, attr := range it.Attrs {
        s += fmt.Sprintf("%s%s:%s", sep, attr.Name.Local, attr.Value)
        sep = " "
    }
    s += "}}"
    return
}
```

### Solution 2

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25534187/246801) for the same question exmeplifies making your own unmarshaller, like you suggested.  I don't know what kind of structure you expect.  I don't know generics (maybe there's a cleaner solution with generics), so I came up with the following.  The Protocol and Packet structs remain the same, the big change comes with Instruction:

```golang
type Instruction struct {
    name string

    arrayAttrs struct{ name, type_ string }
    fieldAttrs struct {
        name, type_ string
        optional    bool
    }
}
```

and its unmarshaller:

```golang
type Instruction struct {
    name string

    array *Array
    field *Field
}

type Array struct {
    name, type_ string
}

type Field struct {
    name, type_ string
    optional    bool
}

func (it *Instruction) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    it.name = start.Name.Local

    switch it.name {
    case "array":
        it.array = &Array{}
        for _, attr := range start.Attr {
            value := attr.Value
            switch attr.Name.Local {
            case "name":
                it.array.name = value
            case "type":
                it.array.type_ = value
            }
        }
    case "field":
        it.field = &Field{}
        for _, attr := range start.Attr {
            value := attr.Value
            switch attr.Name.Local {
            case "name":
                it.field.name = value
            case "type":
                it.field.type_ = value
            case "optional":
                vb, _ := strconv.ParseBool(value)
                it.field.optional = vb
            }
        }
    }

    return d.Skip()
}

func (it Instruction) String() (s string) {
    switch it.name {
    case "array":
        s = fmt.Sprintf("{array: {name:%s type:%s}}", it.array.name, it.array.type_)
    case "break":
        s = "{break: {}}"
    case "field":
        s = fmt.Sprintf("{field: {name:%s type:%s optional:%t}}", it.field.name, it.field.type_, it.field.optional)
    }
    return
}
```

Using the same unmarshalling code in main (from above):

```
{array: {name:positions type:NpcUpdatePosition}}
{break: {}}
{array: {name:attacks type:NpcUpdateAttack}}
{break: {}}
{array: {name:chats type:NpcUpdateChat}}
{break: {}}
{field: {name:hp type:short optional:true}}
{field: {name:tp type:short optional:true}}
```

### Solution 3

Drawing inspiration from the [RawMessage (Unmarshal) example in the JSON documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#example-RawMessage-Unmarshal), it looks like embracing the any type can allow the simplest struct representation I've tried so far:

```golang
type Protocol struct {
    Packets []Packet `xml:"packet"`
}

type Packet struct {
    Family  string `xml:"family,attr"`
    Action  string `xml:"action,attr"`
    Comment string `xml:"comment"`

    Instructions []any `xml:",any"`
}

type Array struct {
    Name string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Type string `xml:"type,attr"`
}

type Break struct{}

type Field struct {
    Name     string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Type     string `xml:"type,attr"`
    Optional bool   `xml:"optional,attr"`
}
```

which makes using the structs look more straight-forward (for my sensibilities):

```golang
var p Protocol
must(xml.Unmarshal([]byte(sXML), &p))
for _, it := range p.Packets[0].Instructions {
    fmt.Printf("%T: %+v\n", it, it)
}
```

to get:

```
*main.Array: &{Name:positions Type:NpcUpdatePosition}
*main.Break: &{}
*main.Array: &{Name:attacks Type:NpcUpdateAttack}
*main.Break: &{}
*main.Array: &{Name:chats Type:NpcUpdateChat}
*main.Break: &{}
*main.Field: &{Name:hp Type:short Optional:true}
*main.Field: &{Name:tp Type:short Optional:true}
```

So, I guess that means that UnmarshalXML must carry the balance of logic and work:

```golang
func (p *Packet) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    for _, attr := range start.Attr {
        switch attr.Name.Local {
        case "family":
            p.Family = attr.Value
        case "action":
            p.Action = attr.Value
        }
    }

    for {
        t, err := d.Token()
        if atEOF(err) {
            break
        }

        if ee, ok := t.(xml.EndElement); ok {
            if ee.Name.Local == start.Name.Local {
                break
            }
        }

        se, ok := t.(xml.StartElement)
        if !ok {
            continue
        }

        if se.Name.Local == "comment" {
            var s string
            must(d.DecodeElement(&s, &se))
            p.Comment = s
            continue
        }

        var dst any
        switch se.Name.Local {
        default:
            continue
        case "array":
            dst = new(Array)
        case "break":
            dst = new(Break)
        case "field":
            dst = new(Field)
        }
        must(d.DecodeElement(dst, &se))

        p.Instructions = append(p.Instructions, dst)
    }

    return nil
}
```

I still don't understand the *implementation notes* in the documentation for the xml.Unmarshaler type:

> UnmarshalXML decodes a single XML element beginning with the given start element. If it returns an error, the outer call to Unmarshal stops and returns that error. UnmarshalXML must consume exactly one XML element. One common implementation strategy is to unmarshal into a separate value with a layout matching the expected XML using d.DecodeElement, and then to copy the data from that value into the receiver. Another common strategy is to use d.Token to process the XML object one token at a time. UnmarshalXML may not use d.RawToken.

One thing I learned through trial-and-error was the meaning of 'UnmarshalXML must consume exactly one XML element.'.  To satisfy that constraint I added the check to see if the decoder encountered an end element with a name that matches the starting element:

```golang
if ee, ok := t.(xml.EndElement); ok {
    if ee.Name.Local == start.Name.Local {
        break
    }
}
```

though, I now realize this wouldn't work nested elements. A simple depth counter/tracker should clear that up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this actually sent me on a very similar path using `xml.Name` as in your first example. Instead of collecting all the attributes in a single slice I ended up making them all pointer types so an unset value would be `nil`, so they could remain well named in the model. Here's what I ended up with: https://github.com/ethanmoffat/eolib-go/blob/master/internal/xml/models.go#L55

Comment: @E.Moffat, great... I just added a third alternative... I like it the most as it allows the cleanest data/struct representation. I looked over your code, good work! :)

Comment: Awesome! Solution 3 is exactly what I was looking for originally, I just didn't think it was possible. I think that would make my code a lot easier to work with, so I'll try integrating that solution and let you know what happens.